# Search box a table ado.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I'm trying to pull out a search box function through ADO.NET

So far I have a View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Find Pokemon: @Html.TextBox("searchKey")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />


    </p>
}


@foreach (var item in Model){...
```

That works. 
Then I have the controller:

```
    public ActionResult NoEF(string searchKey)
    {
        Pokemon poke = new Pokemon();

            poke.Search(searchKey);
        //poke.Search(poke.Poke_Name, poke.Poke_Color);

        return View(poke);

    }
```

Which is supposed to redirect to the Pokemon.cs file. It has a class that's supposed to connect to the database, perform a query and then display the info based on that's typed into the search box like so:

```
 public List<Pokemon> Search(string searchKey)
        {
            List<Pokemon> pokemons = new List<Pokemon>();


            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename = 'C:\Users\Pokedatabase.mdf'; Integrated Security = True");

            //Default order by name
            string query = "SELECT        Pokemon.*, Poketype.* FROM Pokemon INNER JOIN" +
                           "  Poketype ON Pokemon.P_Type = Poketype.Type_Id" +
                            " Where Pokemon.Poke_Name = '"+ searchKey + "' || Poke_Color = '"+ searchKey + "' order by Poke_Name";

            //Opens up a connection to the database
            con.Open();
```

My issue is that after opening a connection, I'm not quite sure of what to put in there. I've googled everywhere. And so far I'm using a YOLO code that obviously won't work:

```
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        //Creates a data reader object and supplies it with data
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                dr = dr(dr.GetValue(0) + " - " + dr.GetValue(1) + " - " + dr.GetValue(2));
            }
            dr.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
    }

    return pokemons;
}
```

Any suggestions to improvements on that?

Comment: What does your `Pokemon` class look like? What properties are you trying to set from your database?

Comment: `public partial class Pokemon

    {
        public int Poke_Id { get; set; }
        public string Poke_Name { get; set; }
        public string Poke_Color { get; set; }
        public int Poke_Hp { get; set; }
        public int P_Type { get; set; }

        public virtual Poketype Poketype { get; set; }
`

Comment: With ADO.NET you have to set all of your properties from the `SqlDataReader` yourself. `Poke_Name = dr["Poke_Name"];` and so on.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create A class of Pokemon like :

```
    public class Pokemon
    {
      public string Name{get;set;}
      public string Type{get;set;}
    }
```

you can add any properties you like as in your data, i took only two of them as for help.
than in your search function do like this after:

```
        con.open();

        sqlDs = new DataSet();
        conOpen();
        var sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
        sqlComm.Connection = con;
        sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlComm.CommandText = query;
        sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlComm);
        sqlDa.Fill(sqlDs);
        conClose();
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt = sqlDs.Tables[0];
```

Now, after this fill the list of Pokemon type as:

```
        var list = (from a in dt
                    select new Pokemon
                    {
                        Name = a.Name,
                        Type = a.Type
                    }).ToList();

            return list;
```

return this list to the controller in search function